# Distinguishing and Processing Only One Div Item with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a list which item is folding/unfolding with CSS and JQuery.

When I click the first item to unfold it, all items are unfolded because the names of class are same.

Can I distinguish only one item from the list keeping class names same?

My code is below and sharing the same class name.

```
<div class="flip">Unfold!</div>
<div class="panel">Hello<br>This is First</div>

<div class="flip">unfold 2!</div>
<div class="panel">hello<br>This is Second</div>
```

And the JQuery code is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideDown("slow");
});
});
```

Does JQuery have a command to distinguish items?

You can look around my source below as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/qmavqug6/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The `.panel` element you want to target is the next sibling of the clicked `flip`, so use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the target `panel`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/397raqzz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.next` for this

```
$(this).next(".panel").slideDown("slow");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmavqug6/1/)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery has an  `:nth-child()`  http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ which can allow you to select specific items.

`$(".panel:nth-child(1)")` for example will get the first matched item.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The question was "Does JQuery have a command to distinguish items?". The answer is yes it does. I answered the question, no downvote is needed.